# Issue in getting started on corda

Tags: blockchain, corda

Referred below link 
https://docs.corda.net/releases/release-M10.1/tutorial-cordapp.html

Click open, then navigate to the folder where you cloned the cordapp-tutorial and click OK.

Next, IntelliJ will show a bunch of pop-up windows. One of which requires our attention:
Click the ‘import gradle project’ link. A dialogue will pop-up. Press OK. Gradle will now obtain all the project dependencies and perform some indexing. It usually takes a minute or so. If you miss the ‘import gradle project’ dialogue, simply close and re-open IntelliJ again to see it again.

Question: I can't find the link. And there were no pop up windows. I followed the instructions. Don't know why I am stuck

Comment: Which version of IntelliJ are you using? And do you have a specific reason to be on M10? If you're happy to use the latest stable version, try https://docs.corda.net/tutorial-cordapp.html. Also if you can see a little speech bubble in the bottom-right corner, and click on that.

Comment: Technically, the `Import gradle project` link should be in the Event Log: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/event-log.html.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should refer to M13 or M14 and check out on it, second "Question: I can't find the link." it's not a question....please provide a more detailed one